# Java XLS get cell through columnname

Tags: java, excel, xls, rft

I'm currently working on a project where I need to edit XLS with Java. The first row of the xls is a row with columnnames. I want to use the columnname to insert data in the cells below. Instead of using getCell to insert a prefix number, I want the application to use a variable string to insert the data. (The comment part is info I scribbled for myself; it might be useful).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would done like this:

- create a `Map` object
- store the **index** value of each column into `Map`
- then, `row.getCell (theNameIndexMap.get("A_COLUMN_NAME"))` would meet your requirement

And, make sure each column name is **UNIQUE**...

Answer (score 1):

Create a Map to store the ColumnName and Index.

You can use objMap.get(columnName) whenever you need the index to passed to the cell.